# Precision Recall for binary classification problems

Tags: classification, precision, roc, supervised-learning, precision-recall

I have seen in the internet when people talk about binary classification problems they only report one precision and one recall for the entire model. (Sure it makes sense to report one accuracy). This makes sense if your objective is cancer and non-cancer therefore people who already have cancer and are identified as cancer are true positive. However consider consider you want to classify people are man or woman and you have the confusion matrix as follow :

```
 man    4      2

 woman  3      1
```

In this case it really makes no sense to have one precision and recall for the entire system. The precision and recall for men are different from women. I am wondering how many precision and recall are described in this scenario since you can look at true positive from women perspective as well(This is different from disease case) ?

Comment: Have you considered PR might not be the right tool for the job? Also this might be context dependent: are you an advertiser trying to sell pregnancy tests or men's shaving razors? In both case you'd have a clear criteria for positivity.

Comment: What is wrong with reporting two precision or two recalls? one per class?